# C++ Printing text in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm reading the individual lines from a text file and attempting to print them out on individual lines in the command prompt, but the text just flashes really quickly and disappears.

I is set to the number of lines in readable.txt

```
cout << "These are the names of your accounts: " << endl;
for (int b = 1; b <= i; b++)
{
    fstream file("readable.txt");

    GotoLine(file, b);

    string line;
    file >> line;

    cout << line << endl;
}   
cin.ignore();                       
break;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**error:**
Opening a fstream inside a loop? that is suicide, your fstream is always the same why are you opening it for every iteration?

The text probably disappears because your program reaches the end and auto exits you should make him wait before the break or before it reaches the end

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reopen file every time and invoke `GotoLine(file, b);` you can open it once outside the for loop and read strings via `std::getline(file, line)`.

If you want to watch the output, insert `system("pause")` just after the for loop. If you want to pause input after each line, insert `getchar()` in the end of the for loop (inside of it)

Answer (score 0):

The break is nonsense (if the snippet is not in a loop or switch.
My guess for the disappearing text is an interference with a IDE. Try it in a terminal/console.
And as in the other answers, file open should be outside the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void GotoLine(fstream &f, int b)
{
    char buf [999];
    while (b > 0) { f.getline (buf, 1000); b--; }
}

int main ()
{
    int i = 5;
    cout << "These are the names of your accounts: " << endl;
    for (int b = 1; b <= i; b++)
    {
        fstream fl("readable.txt");
        GotoLine(fl, b);

        string line;
        fl >> line;

      cout << line << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly avoid opening a file inside a for loop. You are doing a lot of mess here. 
Try this code

```
std::ifstream file("readable.txt");
file.open("readable.txt");

if(file.fail())
{
    std::cout << "File cannot be opened" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

std::string line; 

while std::getline(file, line)  // This line allows to read a data line by line 
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}

file.close(); 

system("PAUSE"); // This line allows the console to wait 
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```